# Figuring out if 2 strings are similar in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string-comparison

I have a table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and a column `value`. I tried comparing strings with `SOUNDS LIKE`. That works well most of the time, but not for all cases.

Where it works: `SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value SOUNDS LIKE 'Stechbeitel m.Schlagkappe 6mm';`

This gives me other results such as `Stechbeitel m.Schlagkappe 20mm`, which is ok.

Another query however does not work: `SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value SOUNDS LIKE '300 mm Hygiene Staender St.weissalu.';`

Its supposed to find a string `300 mm Hygiene Staender St.schwarz`, but it doesnt. Whats the reason here? I tried the `soundex()` values for `300 mm Hygiene Staender St.schwarz` and `300 mm Hygiene Staender St.weissalu.` and they are of course not the same, but almost the same, which makes sense. The `soundex()` values are `M25235362324` and `M252353623262`.

So, how could I either make the `SOUNDS LIKE` work for all similar strings or maybe match the `soundex()` values, as they are very similar?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try `SELECT value FROM ... WHERE LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO(soundex(value), soundex('300 mm Hygiene Staender St.weissalu.')) < X` ? example https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/levenshtein-and-levenshtein_ratio-functions-for-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to apply the [`SOUNDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) operator twice. The idea here is that similar strings will have slightly different soundex coding, but whose codes will have the same soundex sound.

```
SELECT value_ 
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar 
WHERE SOUNDEX(SOUNDEX(value_)) = SOUNDEX(SOUNDEX(<your_comparison_string>))
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHmhFjb8d7keDd7Y2XpF1s/0).

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar idea, but this is returning too many results :-(.

Comment: I have some more ideas. Could you add more samples to your data with what should match and what shouldn't to your sample data?